# Excel Chart set axis units as 1, 25, 50,

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, axis

I've not been able to find to a solution for this.

I plot some data as an X Y (Scatter) chart and want the horizontal axis to begin at 1 and then show the units which are multiples of 25, i.e the chart begins 1, 25, 50, ... Is there a way to do this?

I only know how to have the chart begin with 0, 25, 50, ..., or 1, 26, 51, ...

Comment: Unlikely to be possible as the axis settings only defines major and minor "steps".

Comment: I'm wondering what's wrong with starting the axis at zero?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a little skullduggery.

[image]

Add a second data series to your graph, with your desired labels as the x-values, and 0 for all the y-values.

Format the horizontal axis as "No Axis", and format the new series to have the + sign as the marker, black line, no fill, and no shadow.

Add data labels to the series, selecting "X-value" as the label, and positioning them below the data points.

Note: If you want just inner or outer tick marks, you can set the marker to "No marker" and add y-error bars.  That will let you set the length of the error bar (tick mark) and choose inner, outer or both.